# Get a suds web service XML sub group in a python list?

Tags: python, xml, web-services, suds

Suds is returning sub group XML elements as a long strings of 'x = "y"' as seen below. How can I get sub xml elements to return into a data set so I dont have to write string parsing code?

**Details:**

I call a web service with suds as normal like this:

```
myWebServiceData=client.service.getMethod("P1", "P2", "P3")
```

It Returns a dictionary as I would like however it looks like this:

```
myWebServiceData = { elm1: "data1", elm2: "data2", elm3: ["(data3){ elm4 = data4 elm5 = data5 elm6 = data6" ]}
```

So any data under data4 is a list with a length of 1. like this:

```
print myWebServiceData['elm4'][0]
elm4 = "data4" 
elm5 = "data5"
elm6 = "data6
```

"

However my xml looks like this (as seen in my logger):

```
<elm1>data1</elm1>
<elm2>data2</elm2>
<elm3>
   <elm4>data4</elm4>
   <elm5>data5</elm5>
   <elm6>data6</elm6>
</elm3>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out you the string given can easily be converted into a dictionary:

```
myElm3Dict = dict(myWebServiceData['elm3'][0])
```